# Outlook Appointment Timezone display issue

Tags: .net, outlook, calendar, office365api

I'm a developer in England and I'm currently on British Summertime.

When adding an appointment via Office 365 API using the .Net Client Library for Office 365 Mail, Calendar and Contact API, the Timezone button on the Appointment when viewed in Outlook (2016) can't be un-clicked and the timezone list is always displaying UTC

See this image for an example

[image: (See this image for an example)]

When I hover over the appointment in the Calendar within Outlook, the time in BST is shown (as expected).

See this image for an example

[image: (see this image for an example)]

However, when I add an appointment to the calendar manually, the timezone button is not checked/clicked and I can freely check/uncheck the button. Also, when I click the button, the correct timezone is displayed (Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London).

Note that the appointment shows the correct times when viewing via Office 365 online - https://outlook.office.com/owa/

Why is this happening?

**More Information:**

After a while of searching on Google, I did come across https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/44093e33-133d-4de7-9f67-9ec591453bd0/calendar-meeting-time-zone-display-issue?forum=outlook

However I do not see that option in https://outlook.office.com/owa/

In my code, I set the following properties on the Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices.Event:

```
Private Sub UpdateEvent(ByVal cEvent As [Event], ByVal tCalendar As t_Calendar)
    Dim cLocation As New Location()
    cLocation.DisplayName = tCalendar.sLocation

    Dim cBody As New ItemBody()
    cBody.ContentType = BodyType.HTML
    cBody.Content = tCalendar.sDescription

    cEvent.Subject = tCalendar.sSummary
    cEvent.Location = cLocation

    cEvent.IsAllDay = False
    cEvent.Start = New DateTimeOffset(tCalendar.dtStart)
    cEvent.End = New DateTimeOffset(tCalendar.dtEnd)

    cEvent.Body = cBody
End Sub
```

I have followed the guide https://github.com/jasonjoh/office365-azure-guides/blob/master/RegisterAnAppInAzure.md to Register an Office 365 API app in Azure AD.

Comment: Hey Richard Wilson, I am facing the same issue. I'm in IST (UTC+5.30). I'm creating events using the graph API's in UTC. The events show up in the right timezone when viewed in the calendar on the desktop client. On opening the event, the timezone is changed to UTC and cannot be edited. How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think we are confusing two different issues here. This problem with Outlook application is not related to Office365 API issue. If you create an event using Outlook application, as you said, you can change the TimeZone, now send the event, and then try to edit that event (in Outlook), you will see that you are Not able to change the timezone. So it is not only happening with Office365 API. It seems like Outlook does not let you change TimeZone once it is set.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I think the issue is with the .Net client library I have been using to add appointments via Office365 API. When I use raw http requests with https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events and specify the "TimeZone" as "GMT Standard Time" then the Time Zone button  on the Outlook appointment can be un-clicked and the time zone displays as (Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London)